# Blackberry webworks: onHardwareKey keyUp event?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, blackberry, blackberry-webworks

Is there a possibility to capture the key up event of a hardware key on blackberry-webworks?

The `blackberry.system.event.onHardwareKey` is fired when pressing the key down, but i want a value to increase as long as I'm pressing the key, so i need to get the key up event to stop increasing the value...

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We've found the Kitchen Sink to be a great resource for looking at things WebWorks can do
http://blackberry.github.com/WebWorks-Samples/kitchenSink/

Take a look at the User Input - Respond to physical user input : Keyboard Events example and see if it helps:
http://blackberry.github.com/WebWorks-Samples/kitchenSink/html/browser/keyevents.html

NOTE: Use Firebug/Chromes Developer Tools to view the keyevents.js file doing all the work.